# Can I transfer videos from iTunes to an iPad not associated with it?

Tags: itunes, ipad, video

I've got some (non-DRM) videos in iTunes that I'd like to transfer to my wife's iPad. She bought the iPad and set it up without ever connecting it to a computer, so it's never been synched with iTunes anywhere.

When I plug the iPad into my laptop, I'm asked if I want to register. When I click Register Later, I see this:

[image: Set up new iPad screen]

I'm concerned that selecting Set up as a new iPad will wipe out my wife's settings and / or content. Can I select that option safely, or is there some other way of getting my videos onto her iPad?

**Update:** I should note that I can't simply drag video files to the iPad in the iTunes sidebar. The iPad shows up like this:

[image: iPad in sidebar]

Right clicking on the iPad in the sidebar produces only two options: "Eject iPad" or "Restore from backup". No option to Transfer Purchases, though the iPad and Mac are both configured to use the same Apple ID for the iTunes Store.

I assume I should be looking for the iPad to show up, as an iPhone does, with a list of media types underneath it so that I can view / drag things to its library.

I've also confirmed I can't drag video downloaded from the iTunes Store, either, so it's probably not a format conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that, in fact, selecting "Set up as new iPad" in the dialog shown in the question *had no effect on the iPad*. This may or may not be because I had set iTunes to prevent iOS devices from syncing automatically in its Settings.

iTunes brought up the standard iOS-device user interface, and I was able to drag and drop media onto the iPad from there.

Answer (score 2):

New set up will wipe out everything.

You can plug iPad into her iTunes and mark the option "Manually manage music and videos", save (sync), then plug again on your computer.

If you are careful when cross connecting, you can prevent cross-syncing the same information from two computers for this iPad, but still have each computer take care of part of the sync "situation".

other option is:
Copy the videos to her iTunes, then add them to her iPad from there.

Last option:
- Backup all the app data, videos, music and even pdf files with third party software (TouchCopy, iExplorer, PhoneToMac or any other you like). Do not backup system files.
- Set up the iPad.
- Copy everything back using the same third party software.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but note the second sentence of my question: wouldn't plugging the iPad into *her* copy of iTunes *for the first time* just yield the same result?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't really notice that. But if this is the case, can't you simply ignore this screen, go to your iTunes videos and drag-and-drop the video onto her iPad in the left column, without actually selecting it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. See my update to the question.

Comment: Just edited answer. Hope it helps. You can find some freeware apps to copy i-Phones, Pods and Pads.